# Powered On HP Laptop and got the "No Operating System Was Found on System" Error

Tags: boot, ssd, bios, windows-11, hp

So I put my laptop to sleep yesterday and came back today to find myself trapped with the message "No operating system was found on this system." Do you want to reinstall the operating system?  WARNING: This operation will destroy the existing content on the drive." Obviously I have a lot of information that I don't want to lose; please help me if you have any ideas on how I can repair this.
Things I've tried so far with no success:

- I checked if the hard drive was detected by BIOS and it passed all the test.
- Checked if the hard drive is the first on the boot list
- Rested the BIOS to factory and custom setting (some people said check the date and time on BIOS and they were correct as well)
- Made a bootable WIN11 drive and tried to fix the MBR, the command worked but unfortunately with no success ( while running the diskpart command I noticed that my SSD was listed but the storage was completely free :( hope this doesn't mean that it got corrupted or my data was erased - I mean I didn't do anything to be erased :(
- I tried a bootable linux distro on flash drive and booted the laptop from the drive, I successfully booted the OS but unfortunately the SSD drive was not being detected on the list of drives.
  Please advise!

Comment: See if a Windows 11 Startup Repair will start the system.  It appears the SSD has a hardware problem, so not likely the Startup Repair will work. Consider taking the drive to a local agency to see if any data can be recovered.

Comment: Just because HP built-in HDD tests, doesn’t mean, you have lost a critical sector containing the BCD required to boot your system

Comment: Can you add more details on the *"the storage was completely free"* what exactly did it say? Also in the "bootable WIN11" can you try other ways of listed the content of the SSD (like `dir`)?

Comment: @John When I created a bootable Windows 11 flash drive, attempted the startup repair option, and it did nothing, failing instantly. If none of the other measures given here work, I will consider taking it to a local agency.

Comment: That is probably what you should do now.

Comment: @Ramhound What do you suggest I do?

Comment: @YisroelTech So when I booted with bootable WIN 11 flash drive, went to the windows repair option and selected CMD, there I used the Diskpart command which listed all disks, here it detected the SSD drive and it had two columns one of them was the size of the SSD and the other one free space, both of them were the same number. Not sure how to do that 'dir', I tried the command, it only shows the flash drive content. Any advise?

Comment: @Arkan - If you lost the sector of the disk, that contains the BCD, there really isn't a solution other than to reinstall Windows.

Comment: @Arkan, the Free column for the `LIST DISK` command in `diskpart` is merely the space on the disk not allocated to any partition on the disk (so not relevant, since all the disk space can be allocated to partitions.) What you could do is do the same `diskpart` and try the `LIST VOLUME`. Post the results of that what it shows there for all the SSD partitions

Comment: @YisroelTech This [is](https://prnt.sc/Wniou-olERyA) what I got

Comment: That doesn't look good, it doesn't find any volumes at all for the SSD. Maybe try to get more info using `SELECT DISK 0` and then `DETAIL DISK'.

Comment: I got [this](https://prnt.sc/MC1OBrq9nPLB)

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid that the data whole disk may have gotten corrupted. If you have any important/valuable data on it, consider consulting a data recovery expert. Otherwise just install Windows from fresh on it.

Answer (score 1):

"I noticed that my SSD was listed but the storage was completely free." As you state, likely the SSD is bad. That is also the device that would have the boot partition and Windows folder, *ergo*, no OS.

1. Do not try to use the built-in SSD (and HDD if present).
2. Using a bootable USB device and external drive, image all drives. From the Linux USB, you can use [dd](https://linuxhint.com/make-disk-images-dd-command-linux/) or [an alternative](https://www.tecmint.com/linux-disk-cloning-tools/) to make image(s), or use third-party rescue media, such as [Macrium Reflect's](https://blog.macrium.com/the-macrium-rescue-environment-cca57a4ebc61), to do so. Try to salvage data by mounting the *image*.
3. If the SSD *cannot* be imaged because it cannot be detected, likely there is nothing you can do to fix it. However, you could try putting it in an [external USB enclosure](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=usb%20ssd%20enclosure) to see if data can be salvaged.
4. If there is any chance the machine is still on warranty, contact HP.
5. After saving data, you can let the machine try to restore itself... but do not have great expectations, since that SSD may be bad.

Comment: So, I'm getting [this](https://prnt.sc/DTQoeuxfxOdG) after following the first guide you shared; there's nothing listed beneath the last raw compared to what the guy in the guide got. Please note that my disk only had one primary drive/partition. My question is, should I proceed, or does it appear that everything is gone/corrupted at this point?